# SQL Server: matching two tables and results in the order of proper column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `JOB` and `EMP`; structure and values are like this:

```
CREATE TABLE JOB 
(
    JOBID SMALLINT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    JOBNAME CHAR(15)
);

CREATE TABLE EMP
(
    EMPID SMALLINT, 
    JOBID SMALLINT, 
    SAL SMALLINT, 
    CITYID SMALLINT,
    YEAR SMALLINT,
    STATUS CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO JOB(JOBID, JOBNAME) 
VALUES (1, 'DEVELOPMENT'),
       (2, 'DEVELOPMENT'),
       (3, 'TESTING'),
       (4, 'TESTING'),
       (7, 'TESTING'),
       (9, 'RESEARCH'),
       (8, 'HR');

INSERT INTO EMP (EMPID , JOBID, SAL, CITYID, YEAR, STATUS) 
VALUES (100, 1, 1000, 10, 2015, 'A'),
       (200, 2, 2000, 10, 2015, 'A'),
       (300, 1, 2500, 20, 2015, 'A'),
       (400, 3, 1000, 10, 2016, 'A'),
       (500, 6, 3000, 10, 2015, 'E'),
       (600, 8, 1000, 30, 2015, 'A'),
       (700, 8, 2000, 10, 2015, 'E'),
       (800, 9, 1500, 10, 2015, 'A');
```

I want to display all jobname count and avg salaries; for the jobname if jobid's not exists then display 0

For the given input `cityid` , `YEAR` and `STATUS` ( `Emp` table), take all `jobid` for each `jobname` (from `job` table ) and match in `Emp` table, if exists display `count` (count of `jobid` present in `Emp` table) and `avgsal else 0` for `count` and `avgsal`. And `Sal` is calculated based on `Status`. If `Status` is 'A' Sal goes to `Status-A-Sal else Status-E-Sal`. And for each matched i.e non zero record put 'X' in another field

Output should be like this for `Cityid`'s 10 and 20 year 2015. Results should be displayed first for `Status` 'A' and then `Status` 'E'. Added status type field in result .

```
Cityid  Status-type jobname         count   STATUS      sal
--------------------------------------------------------------
10      STATUSA     development     2       X           1500
10      STATUSA     TESTING         0                   0
10      STATUSA     RESEARCH        1       X           1500 
10      STATUSA     HR              0                   0
10      total                       3                   0
10      STATUSE     development     0                   0
10      STATUSE     TESTING         0                   0
10      STATUSE     RESEARCH        0                   0 
10      STATUSE     HR              1        X          2000
10      total                       1                   2000

20      STATUSA     development     1        X          2500
20      STATUSA     TESTING         0                   0
20      STATUSA     RESEARCH        0                   0 
20      STATUSA     HR              0                   0
20      total                       1                   2500
20      STATUSE     development     0                   0
20      STATUSE     TESTING         0                   0
20      STATUSE     RESEARCH        0                   0 
20      STATUSE     HR              0                   0
20      total                       0                   0
```

How to bring the results one status after another ?

I've tried like this but its throwing

```
SELECT C.CITYID  AS CITYID,
           CASE WHEN P.STATUS ='A' THEN 'STATUSA' ELSE 'STATUSE' END AS STATUS_TYPE ,
           COALESCE(J.JOBNAME, 'TOTAL') AS JOBNAME,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN P.STATUS ='A' THEN P.CITYID END ) AS COUNT ,
           COALESCE(AVG(CAST(CASE WHEN P.STATUS = 'A' THEN P.SAL END AS DECIMAL(13,2)))/12 , 0) AS "AVG SAL",
           COUNT(CASE WHEN P.STATUS ='E' THEN P.CITYID END ) AS  COUNT  ,
           COALESCE(AVG(CAST(CASE WHEN P.STATUS = 'E' THEN P.SAL END AS DECIMAL(13,2)))/12 , 0) AS "AVG SAL"
    FROM JOB1 J
    CROSS JOIN 
            (SELECT DISTINCT CITYID 
                FROM EMP1  B WHERE CITYID = 10

            ) C
    LEFT JOIN EMP1 P ON P.JOBID = J.JOBID 
            AND  P.CITYID = C.CITYID and
            YEAR = 2015
        GROUP BY ROLLUP(C.CITYID,  J.JOBNAME );
```

> ERROR: 
>   Column 'EMP1.STATUS' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: please share the query you have written so far and challenge you are facing then it will be easy to help you.

Comment: added my query in question

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#JOB') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #JOB

CREATE TABLE #JOB 
(
    JOBID SMALLINT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    JOBNAME CHAR(15)
);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EMP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #EMP

CREATE TABLE #EMP
(
    EMPID SMALLINT, 
    JOBID SMALLINT, 
    SAL SMALLINT, 
    CITYID SMALLINT,
    YEAR SMALLINT,
    STATUS CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO #JOB(JOBID, JOBNAME) 
VALUES (1, 'DEVELOPMENT'),
       (2, 'DEVELOPMENT'),
       (3, 'TESTING'),
       (4, 'TESTING'),
       (7, 'TESTING'),
       (9, 'RESEARCH'),
       (8, 'HR');

INSERT INTO #EMP (EMPID , JOBID, SAL, CITYID, YEAR, STATUS) 
VALUES (100, 1, 1000, 10, 2015, 'A'),
       (200, 2, 2000, 10, 2015, 'A'),
       (300, 1, 2500, 20, 2015, 'A'),
       (400, 3, 1000, 10, 2016, 'A'),
       (500, 6, 3000, 10, 2015, 'E'),
       (600, 8, 1000, 30, 2015, 'A'),
       (700, 8, 2000, 10, 2015, 'E'),
       (800, 9, 1500, 10, 2015, 'A');

;with cteJobDict as (
    select
            distinct
            j.JOBNAME
    from
            #JOB j
)
,cteStatusDict as(
    select
            distinct STATUS
    from
            #EMP e
),cteCityDict as (
    select
            distinct CITYID
    from
            #EMP
)
,cteJobStatusCityMatrix as(
    select
            *
    from
            cteJobDict
    cross apply cteStatusDict
    cross apply cteCityDict
)
,cteEmpWithJobName as (
    select
            e.*
            ,j.JOBNAME
    from
            #EMP e
    join    #JOB j on j.JOBID=e.JOBID
), cteData as (
SELECT
        m.CITYID
        ,CASE WHEN m.STATUS ='A' THEN 'STATUSA' ELSE 'STATUSE' end as [Status-type]
        ,CASE WHEN m.STATUS ='A' THEN 1 ELSE 3 end as [Status-order]
        ,m.JOBNAME
        ,count(distinct e.EMPID) count
        ,iif(count(distinct e.EMPID)>0,'X','') status
        ,isnull(avg(e.sal),0) sal
FROM
        cteJobStatusCityMatrix m
left join cteEmpWithJobName e on e.CITYID=m.CITYID and e.STATUS=m.STATUS and e.JOBNAME=m.JOBNAME and e.YEAR=2015
where
        m.CITYID in (10,20)
group by
        m.CITYID
        ,m.STATUS
        ,m.JOBNAME
union
SELECT
        m.CITYID
        ,'total' as [Status-type]
        ,CASE WHEN m.STATUS ='A' THEN 2 ELSE 4 end as [Status-order]
        ,null
        ,count(distinct e.EMPID) count
        ,iif(count(distinct e.EMPID)>0,'X','') status
        ,isnull(avg(e.sal),0) sal
FROM
        cteJobStatusCityMatrix m
left join cteEmpWithJobName e
            on e.CITYID=m.CITYID
            and e.STATUS=m.STATUS
            and e.JOBNAME=m.JOBNAME
            and e.YEAR=2015 -- here goes year
where
        m.CITYID in (10,20) -- here goes cityid
group by
        m.CITYID
        ,m.STATUS)
select
        CITYID
        ,[Status-type]
        ,JOBNAME
        ,count
        ,status
        ,sal
from
        cteData
order by
        CITYID
        ,[Status-order]
```